# How to ask an object to return its class and methods source as a string?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I want to find the source of a Class and its methods *(including all variables too, local , instance, class , class instance etc)* and return them as a string or a collection of strings.

I have found `MethodNode>>sourceText` and `CompiledMethod>>sourceCode` but I have no clue how to send these messages or if they are the messages I am looking for.

Also any pointers as to how to navigate the Pharo syntax by code using something like `AST` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use #definition to get source string both from _Class_ objects and _CompiledMethod_ objects. Other than that I don't understand what are you asking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First ask the class of your object, then ask, for example, all the methods defined in this class and then collect the source-code of each method:

```
'Pharo' class methods collect: [ :each | each sourceCode ]
```

You can find the relevant methods for other properties of your class in the *accessing protocols* of `Behavior`, a superclass of `Class`.

Comment: In GNU-Smalltalk `methodDictionary` will answer the receiver’s method dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Martin there are also other ways of doing this for example

```
(Object compiledMethodAt: #printString) sourceCode
```

will return the source code for a specific method.

In case we want to navigate through the syntax using AST of a method:

```
( Object compiledMethodAt: #halt ) ast nodesDo:[ :node |  node inspect].
```

Take a look at RBProgramNode and its relevant subclasses to have taste what is possible for navigating and processing source code.

Answer (score 1):

And depending on your exact needs, you should be careful about traits, extension methods and methods defined in superclasses.